# Issue when importing JSON via 'require' in Meteor

Tags: meteor

The following code works to load a local, static JSON file:

```
var stories = require('../stories/stories.json');
```

Now I want to load a file based on a variable, e.g. do something like this:

```
var storiesPath = '../stories/stories.json';
var stories = require(storiesPath);
```

But this triggers an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../stories/stories.json'
    at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:123:19)
    at meteorInstall.server.main.js (server/main.js:7:15)
```

Is there any way to get this working? I assume that I could load my file via the Meteor http package instead but I'd rather not add another package if I can avoid it.

Thanks for your hints

Comment: That actually works fine for me, tested with `fs`: `var x = 'fs'; require(x).readFile` works great.

Comment: `Npm.require`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in the comment, you can easily use a variable in a require, e.g.,

```js
> var x = 'fs';
> require(x).readFile
[Function]
```

So that's not the problem you are dealing with. Are you sure your first case indeed works? It would be surprising. I think you might be running into project file layout issues, due to the use of a relative path. I would stay away from that. And fortunately you can quite easily by using an [asset](https://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html)! You can put your json file in `private/` in your project folder and then use:

```js
const stories = JSON.parse(Assets.getText('stories.json'));
```

Comment: I'm still not sure why my require with a path taken from a variable does not work. Probably the difference is that in your test you used a module where I used a JSON file.
Anyway: the JSON.parse option works like a charm. Many thanks for this option !